# Tensorflow Object Detection API ( TF 2.0) GPU not working

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to run object detection API from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection.
I have installed the API as per the instructions.

When running object_detection_tutorial.ipynb using GPU, nothing is happening at
`for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS: show_inference(detection_model, image_path)` for sometime and the kernel dies afterwards.

However, the same code is working when I'm using the CPU.

Following is the config of my machine:

- Windows 10
- TF2.0.0
- CUDA:10.0.130
- cuDNN:7.6.4
- Graphics:GeForce GTX 1050

Comment: check your terminal or anaconda prompt to see what error messages are being generated. For reference, I got an "UnknownError: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize" when running a large model on: 
tensorflow-gpu 2.0
CUDA 10.0
cuDNN 7.6.5

Eventually downgraded cuDNN to 7.6.2 and the models are training without error now. I don't have the technical aptitude to explain what's going on except that I got lucky when trying different versions of CUDA and cuDNN on tensorflow-gpu 2.0.

Comment: @iatechicken Invoking ptxas not supported on Windows
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. This message will be only logged once.-- This is the message that appears in the terminal before it stops.

Comment: so... I had to uninstall and reinstall tensorflow-gpu 2.0 last night and I started running into the same "invoking ptxas not supported on windows" error. Unfortunately, this looks like a recent open issue on TF. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7640

Comment: @iatechicken did u by chance try it out the older versions of TensorFlow and Cuda/Cudnn?

Comment: not yet. but I think we're on the same page... for me, I was thinking the following 3 options: [1] upgrade CUDA to 10.1 (I already failed with 10.2 before downgrading to 10.0) [2] upgrading the tensorflow to either nightly or 2.0 alpha  [3] downgrading tensorflow to 1.x version (not sure which one's most stable)

Comment: @iatechicken please let me know if you find any solution regarding this. Thanks, I'm also trying

Comment: I was running into this ptax issue whenever I tried to fit the model with keras, using validation_split argument. For my case, I haven't made any changes to my configuration, but instead of using validation_split argument, I split my dev data ahead and then used 'validation_data' argument to specify the dev data. I still see the ptax message show up on the terminal, but the training goes through without hanging.

Answer (score 0):

with the following config (windows 10, cuda 10.0.13, cudnn 7.6.3, Tensorflow 2.0.0, GTX 1050 laptop) I add a similar problem with jupyter notebook when launching final code part :

```
for image_path in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
   show_inference(detection_model, image_path)
```

The code is launched then the kernel fails. using nvidia-smi on cmd one can see that the code is going toward the GPU up to 90% of its capabilities. But it fails due to a lack of memory as one can see in the command prompt. GTX 1050 could not be enough for this type of computation

```
 2020-02-16 09:41:45.057354: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:239] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.93GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
```